# Configuring log4j with IDE / pyspark shell to log to console and file using properties file

Tags: python, java, logging, pyspark, log4j

In my development env on my laptop (Ubuntu box), I write my "pyspark code" and run it through `pytest` to test. I inject the spark session that's created using `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` into my tests. This "pyspark code" has a bunch of log statements at info level. None of them show up anywhere, so I'm forced to write `print()`, which I later remove.

All I want is:

- Ability to set log level for all my loggers (`My.*`)
- Write to console and file (appenders)
- Some docs that describe the format specs. `%t, %m, %n, %d{YYYY-MM-DD}, ...`

I read:

- [Configuring Logging](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging) in official documentation. It just says add `log4j2.properties`. Could not find any docs on format of `log4j2.properties`. [Sample `log4j2.properties.template`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/log4j2.properties.template) is VERY limited. **NOTE that it says** nothing about using `xml` or other formats, just `properties`.
- [All official log4j2](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22log4j2.properties%22%20site%3Alogging.apache.org) docs point to [the same place](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties), which has no docs on contents of `log4j2.properties`. It gives some samples, but those are useless e.g. where do I specify filename for a file appender (not rolling file appender).
- I even tried the [log4j (not log4j2) docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#configuration), this clearly doesn't work (`ConfigurationException: No type attribute provided for Appender my_console`).

I don't want to figure it out by trial and error. Just looking for docs.

`my_spark_module.py`

```py
class MySparkModule:
    def __init__(self, spark):
        self.log = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger('My.SparkModule')
        self.df = spark.createDataFrame([('data1', '2022-01-01T00:00:00'), ('data2', '2022-02-01T00:00:00')],
            schema=['data', 'ts_column'])
        self.log.info('exiting init()')

    def get_count(self):
        return self.df.count()
```

`test_my_spark_module.py`

```py
import pytest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='module')
def spark_session():
    return SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


class TestMySparkModule:
    def test_tables(self):
        spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
        log = spark_session.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger('My.TestMySparkModule')
        log.info('something I wanted to log')
        
        assert MySparkModule(spark_session).get_count() == 1, 'expected count to be 1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful links:

- Log4j2 configuration's [properties file section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) (read slowly and carefully)
- [Full list](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax) of what you can configure.
- [Sample file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/conf/log4j2.properties.template) that is supposed to come with your spark installation. But if you're doing it via pip/virtualenv/poetry, it may not.
- [PatterLayout reference](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#patterns).

---

To setup log4j2 logs from your spark session to `/tmp/my-spark.log` and stdout, place this file in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j2.properties`.

We use poetry virtual env, so `SPARK_HOME` was `<project-root>/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/` and it had no `conf` folder.
So I created conf folder and created `<project-root>/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/conf/log4j2.properties`

Any spark session started using `<project-root>/.venv/bin/pyspark` will use this log4j2 config.

Change `logger.spark_loggers.level = trace|debug|info` to change log level of Spark's loggers to get VERY detailed logs.

NOTE the comments inside the file.

```
# Reload config every X seconds, for testing out changes to
# this file without quiting your spark console session
# monitorInterval = 3  # seconds

property.log_pattern = %d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p [%t-%X{tid}] %c{*.1} - %m%n%exception{full}

appender.my_console.name = my_console
appender.my_console.type = Console
appender.my_console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.my_console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.my_console.layout.pattern = ${log_pattern}

appender.my_file.name = my_file
appender.my_file.type = File
appender.my_file.filename = /tmp/my-spark.log
appender.my_file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.my_file.layout.pattern = ${log_pattern}
# Uncomment if you want to overwrite the log file everytime your program runs
# appender.my_file.Append=false

# For deploying Spark ThriftServer
# SPARK-34128: Suppress undesirable TTransportException warnings involved in THRIFT-4805
appender.my_console.filter.1.type = RegexFilter
appender.my_console.filter.1.regex = .*Thrift error occurred during processing of message.*
appender.my_console.filter.1.onMatch = deny
appender.my_console.filter.1.onMismatch = neutral


# Set all to goto the file
rootLogger.level = warn
# If you want to log everything to console, will be VERY noisy
# rootLogger.appenderRef.my_console.ref = my_console
rootLogger.appenderRef.my_file.ref = my_file

# update to change spark log level (all loggers with org.apache.spark prefix)
logger.spark_loggers.name = org.apache.spark
logger.spark_loggers.level = warn
logger.spark_loggers.additivity = false

# control loggers with com.kash.* prefix
logger.my_loggers.name = com.kash
logger.my_loggers.level = trace
# logger.my_loggers.appenderRef.my_console.ref = my_console
logger.my_loggers.appenderRef.my_file.ref = my_file
logger.my_loggers.additivity = false

# Set the default spark-shell/spark-sql log level to WARN. When running the
# spark-shell/spark-sql, the log level for these classes is used to overwrite
# the root logger's log level, so that the user can have different defaults
# for the shell and regular Spark apps.
logger.repl.name = org.apache.spark.repl.Main
logger.repl.level = warn

logger.thriftserver.name = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver
logger.thriftserver.level = warn

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
logger.jetty1.name = org.sparkproject.jetty
logger.jetty1.level = warn
logger.jetty2.name = org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle
logger.jetty2.level = error
logger.replexprTyper.name = org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper
logger.replexprTyper.level = info
logger.replSparkILoopInterpreter.name = org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter
logger.replSparkILoopInterpreter.level = info
logger.parquet1.name = org.apache.parquet
logger.parquet1.level = error
logger.parquet2.name = parquet
logger.parquet2.level = error

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
logger.RetryingHMSHandler.name = org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler
logger.RetryingHMSHandler.level = fatal
logger.FunctionRegistry.name = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry
logger.FunctionRegistry.level = error
```