# Why spark read JDBC is slower when using predicates?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I tried using predicates in spark.read.jdbc, it makes the read significantly slower.

I have a postgres table to read into spark. I tried below two options:

Option1 -- Using upperBound, lowerBound, numPartitions

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
    .option("url",f"jdbc:postgresql://{host}:{port}/{dbname}")\
    .option("dbtable",dbtable)\
    .option("user",user)\
    .option("password",password)\
    .option("partitionColumn","person_id")\
    .option("numPartitions",2)\
    .option("lowerBound",261461)\
    .option("upperBound",29283487)\
    .load()
df.count()
```

Option2 -- Using predicates

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(
    url = f"jdbc:postgresql://{host}:{port}/{dbname}",
    table = dbtable,
    predicates = ["(person_id < 14772474 OR person_id is null)", "(person_id >= 14772474)"],
    properties = {"user": f"{user}", "password": f"{password}"}
)
df.count()
```

I would expect both options should have similar execution time.
However, option 1 takes 10 seconds while option 2 takes 40 seconds.

I checked postgres log.
Both options have log as:

```
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1 FROM xxxxx.person  WHERE "person_id" < 14772474 or "person_id" is null   
LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT 1 FROM xxxxx.person  WHERE "person_id" >= 14772474
```

Comment: Do they both return the same results?

Comment: They both return same result. Also, they both issue same query to postgres

Comment: can you add some proof that they execute same query on postgresql?

Comment: I find it REALLY hard to believe that "it's executing same queries" in both options AND "it's taking 10 and 40 seconds respectively". To be very sure, can you run each option in a loop 5-10 times, discard the outliers and average the time taken by rest? AND verify the queries with timestamps one more time to be very sure it's same query. Also find out the time it took postgresql to execute each of the queries and see if there is any difference. You can replace `dbtable = f"(select person_id from {dbtable}"` for the test if it's taking too long.

Comment: Can you also add output of `df.explain('formatted')` for both dataframes? Though it might be same I suspect. One other thing is to look through the logs to see WTH is it doing. I'll answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75858726/configuring-log4j-with-ide-pyspark-shell-to-log-to-console-and-file-using-prop) when I get a few mins if it helps.

Comment: I ran more tests. And now the average differences is tiny. I now think the original difference may come from how postgres cache the result

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is to look at your PostgreSQL DB's query history to see what queries are executed by PySpark via JDBC.

Option 1 executes two queries in parallel:

- `select * from dbtable where person_id between 261461 and 14511013`
- `select * from dbtable where person_id between 14511014 and 29283487`

Remember `(29283487 - 261461) / 2 = 14511013`

Two guesses for what option 2 does, my money is on #1:

1. Executes a single query
   `select * from dbtable where <your predicates>`
2. Executes `select * from dbtable`, fetches all results and then applies the predicates/filters in Spark.